# STDERR in a c++  program

Tags: c++, ssh

I have a c++ program that ssh's into a server and runs some commands. If the ssh fails, the error is printed on the screen and the program doesnt know about that.. and it returns a blank list of output. How do i know that ssh has failed? is there a way to redirect STDERR to something other than a FD?

Comment: Does your program launch a third-party ssh client? Or does it use some kind of library?

Comment: Doesn't your ssh client set exit code? By convention, exit code 0 means that everything is OK, nonzero indicates an error. Normally there is no need to parse STDERR just to determine whether a command has failed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the way you actually do the ssh.

If you `system()`, then I may suggest you to use `popen()`. It will allow you to retrieve the output of the program. You'll be able to read it from a file descriptor, instead of it being displayed. Then, you can append a redirection to you command so that stderr is redirected to stdout, and retrieved in the fd.

If you really need your stdout and stderr separated, then you need to implement an advanced `popen()` that will also redirect stderr by yourself. You can do it using `dup2()` and `fork()`.

Comment: i am using dup2()to redirect the fd[write] to the STDOUT_FILENO... so what will the FILENO be if i want to redirect the STDERR and STDOUT to fd??

Comment: so i would jus have to create another fd to redirect the STDERR_FILENO(2) and read from there?